# PDF Export of Google Sheet coming up blank

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have the following script successfully creating a PDF and sending an email, however, the pdf seems to have some errors because it comes up blank. When I debug this function, it is clean, so I don't know how to find the specific issues that is causing the PDF to be blank. I am very new to google scripting so any assistance would be appreciated. I would provide a screenshot of the error I receive when opening the PDF, but I don't have enough rep :(

```
function emailPDF() {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '');

    //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + //export as pdf
        '&size=letter' + //paper size
        '&portrait=true' + //orientation, false for landscape
        '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
        '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide optional
        '&gridlines=false' + //false = hide gridlines
        '&fzr=false' + //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
        '&gid='; //leave ID empty for now, this will be populated in the FOR loop

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs
    var blobs = [];

    //.fetch is called for each sheet, the response is stored in var blobs[]
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        var sheetname = sheets[i].getName();

        //if the sheet is one that you don't want to process,
        //continue' tells the for loop to skip this iteration of the loop
        if (sheetname == "Dropdown Data")
            continue;
        if (sheetname == "Data Log")
            continue;

        var options = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
            }
        }
        options.muteHttpExceptions = true;

        //grab the blob for the sheet
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), options);

        //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
        blobs.push(response.getBlob().setName(sheets[i].getName() + '.pdf'));
        var array_blob = response.getBlob().setName(sheets[i].getName() + '.pdf');
    }

    //Email Evaulation Details
    var chtm_name = ss.getRange('D5').getValue();
    var evaluated_by = ss.getRange('D6').getValue();
    var email_to = ss.getRange('E5').getValue();

    // send email
    var subject = "Customer Happiness Audit Form"
    var message = "Hello " + chtm_name + " - Attached is your audit, completed by " + evaluated_by
    MailApp.sendEmail(email_to, subject, message, {
        attachments: [array_blob]
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you planning on exporting the whole Spreadsheet as-is?

Comment: I only need the active sheet. But your script is working a lot better than mine. Last step is to export the active sheet, not whole spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to export the complete sheet as a pdf, you can use DriveApp. The code will look something similar like this:

```
    function emailPDF() {
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheets = ss.getSheets();
      var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '');

      //Email Evaulation Details
      var chtm_name = ss.getRange('D5').getValue();
      var evaluated_by = ss.getRange('D6').getValue();
      var email_to = ss.getRange('E5').getValue();

      var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
      var attach = {fileName:'ConvertedSpreadsheet.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

      // send email
      var subject = "Customer Happiness Audit Form";
      var message = "Hello " + chtm_name + " - Attached is your audit, completed by " + evaluated_by;
      MailApp.sendEmail(email_to, subject, message, {
        attachments: [attach]
      });
    }
```

**To export a file with a single sheet, the approach should be:

```
// Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);

  // Find and delete the default "Sheet 1", after the copy to avoid triggering an apocalypse
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  // Create a copy of the new file, as a pdf
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Weekly Status.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});

  // Delete the wasted sheet we created, so our Drive stays tidy.
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
```

Comment: Hey Rivero, Thanks for this script. It works great, however, I only need the active sheet, not all sheets. How could that work?

Comment: If thats the case, we need to take the sheet you want to export, create a new file with that only sheet, export that file, and delete. Edited my previous answer to display this.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. I am still trying to understand why my previous script didn't work though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: for those users with non-English language version, that 'Sheet1' could be different, pay attention to change, or modify code to delete all sheets except the last one.